# bash script to stop certain idVendor from mounting

Tags: bash, kernel, mount, udev

I wanted to write a bash script to stop certain idVendors from mounting, my thought was to use `tail -f /var/log/messages` and greping it to idVendor and blocking that certain vendor upon detection, can someone help me on this please?

Comment: Have you already tried something, have you a minimum of code we can work on? Any additional info may be useful.
If I understand you are trying to identify lines like `kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=5a07` and trying to unmount them if mounted? Am I correct?

Comment: actually i tried alot of things to get this to work but since im new to linux none of them did what i wanted and yes thats exactly my question, thanks for replying so fast

Comment: OK, still we need some info. Which distribution of Linux are you using? why do you need to rely on `/var/log/messages` and `idVendors` in a script instead of using `noauto` option for the specific device id in your `fstab`? which kind of peripherals are you trying to unmount? if not strictly related to a scripting language, please consider also to post this question to http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm using centos 7 and well that was the only way that came to my mind:) and what Im trying to do is write a script to disallow mounting of certain usb thumb drive's brand like silicon-power and the reason i need it to be scriptlike is to be able to change the disallowed brand in future, sorry if my question was unclear...

Comment: And i will post it there too for sure thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A `udev` rule would come in handy here. On my arch system I would simply add a rule like this (didn't try it out though). create a file in

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/40-do-not-mount.rules
```

and add a line like this (replacing `[VENDOR ID]` and `[PRODUCT ID]` with the ones from your device, [wildcards are allowed](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#strsubst))

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="[VENDOR ID]", ATTR{idProduct}=="[PRODUCT ID]",ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

then reload

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

test your rule:

```
udevadm test /sys/dev/block/[device]
```

it should output something like

```
...
UDISKS_IGNORE=1
USEC_INITIALIZED=760036464
unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context
```

---

**Some references:**

- [Arch linux docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Writing_udev_rules)
- [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

Comment: this is the same approach I would like to suggest, you were faster than me :)

Comment: Thank you so much i will try it out and let you know, you guys ROCK:)

Comment: Okay, I did all you said but it didn't work:( no error showed up and the device could still be mounted...

Comment: use ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1" instead, i edited my answer

Comment: when i edited that udev and did the test it started reading files from /usr/lib/udev/rules.d and there is something wrong with /sys/dev/block/ i guess cause there are only 9 links in there like 11:0 2:0 253:0 253:1 8:0 8:1 8:16 8:17 8:2 am i doing something wrong here? and there were these two errors at the end of the test: unable to open device '/sys/dev/block/[device]' unload module index

Comment: here is what a guy from superuser.com said: "Write an udev rule that matches devices by their idVendor attribute (ATTR{idVendor}) and writes 0 to the authorized and/or 1 to remove attributes, causing Linux to eject the device." can you please tell me how to do the auth and remove att part?

Comment: you have to replace [device] with your device,in my case it's e.g. 8\:32. you can also use "udevadm test  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdN)" where N should be replaced with the device name your usb stick gets when inserted. or just skip the test.

Comment: okay i did the testing with each of `OPTIONS+="ignore_device" , ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"` but none of them seem to work:/ any help?